# getCacheEntry failed: Cache service responded with 503

Tags: python, github-actions

I am trying to check the lint on the gitubaction. my github action steps are as below

```
  lint:
    name: Lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version-file: '.python-version'
          cache: 'pip'
          cache-dependency-path: 'requirements.txt'
```

Error screenshot   Attached below
[image]

Could you please help me how to fix this?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue today

Comment: Same here, so it does not seem we can do anything about it, seems to be a GitHub problem?

Comment: Also having the same issue today

Comment: Seems to be working again.

Comment: Confirm that I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Got the same issue for java maven packages also.

Comment: https://github.com/bahmutov/npm-install/issues/80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lint:
name: Lint
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Set up Python
    uses: actions/setup-python@v4
    with:
      python-version-file: '.python-version'
  - name: Cache dependencies
    uses: actions/cache@v3
    with:
      path: ~/.cache/pip
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('requirements.txt') }}
      restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
          ${{ runner.os }}-
```

I too faced the same problem. It is because of the `cache` server not responding that includes internal server error or any other.
You can use `actions/cache@v3` instead of the automatic cache by `python` using `cache: 'pip'` because the `action/cache` does the same  but only gives warning on the server error

Answer (score 8):

Seems like the issue is coming from github cache actions.
https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/820

Answer (score 0):

disable cache to solve this problem
look for the line where you see
cache: npm
and comment it out

Answer (score 0):

The Cache service doesn't seem to work. So you need to disable caching to bypass this issue. Remove the line `cache: 'pip'` and commit. You should be fine.